# HTC ONE X: The process "com.android.phone" has stopped?

Tags: hardware, crashes, htc-one-x, cellular-radio, processes

I have just brought a Second had HTC ONE X from an auction site,

When booting up the phone it works fine, with no sim card.

However I have a 2degrees (New Zealand) Micro SIM which is a `snapper sim` I.E. [it has a java applet on the sim to work with NFC as a payment method](http://www.snapper.co.nz/snapper-mobile-security/), when I insert the SIM I get a few seconds later.

> The process com.android.phone has stopped.

I have no cell reception, and, in the settings for "Mobile Network" It has:

> Disconnected because service is unavailable

The process then proceeds to crash again every ~30 seconds. Often displaying the quick notification

> Preparing Sim Card...

The Sim toolkit usually displays:

> SIM Toolkit is not ready or is unsupported.

But the one time I did manage to get into it, it did say it was 2degrees.

I have a custom ROM installed, when I brought the phone it came with a custom ROM, thinking that was going to be the issue I have reflashed it with a different rom, with the same symptoms.

I attempted to log what was going on using logcat, but it got 5K+ entries in a few seconds with the majority seemingly important, so this is viewable here: https://gist.github.com/3977367

Below is my `device.txt` from logcat

```
build.board=unknown
build.brand=htc_europe
build.cpu_abi=armeabi-v7a
build.device=endeavoru
build.display=IMM76D
build.fingerprint=htc_europe/endeavoru/endeavoru:4.0.4/IMM76D/89015.2:user/release-keys
build.host=ABM041
build.id=IMM76D
build.manufacturer=HTC
build.model=HTC One X
build.product=endeavoru
build.tags=release-keys
build.time=1344347715000
build.type=user
build.user=root
version.codename=REL
version.incremental=89015.2
version.release=4.0.4
version.sdk_int=15
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after some extensive troubleshooting I found the issue,

Long story short, you need to have the Snapper application installed.

> [image: Get Snapper on Google Play]
>   [Snapper Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nz.co.snapper.mobile&hl=en)

The issue was confirmed to be the combination of the snapper sim and no application when the SIM was switched with a different network, non-snapper SIM, the phone started working correctly.

Next the SIM was put in a different network, vanilla HTC ONE X, the exact same symptoms occurred.

Leading me to the conclusion that it was the difference in the SIM crashing the process.
After installing the Snapper application the process instantly stopped crashing.